# Как вывести результаты из двух моделей связанных через many2many в шаблоне?

Tags: python, django

Туториал Django:

```
rom django.db import models

class Topping(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Pizza(models.Model):
    # ...
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

Как вывести в шаблоне Пиццы с топпингами понятно:

```
pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()

{% for pizza in pizzas %}
    Пицца: {{ pizza.name }}
    {% for topping in pizza.toppings.all %}
        Топпинг: {{ topping.name }}
    {% endfor %}
% endfor %}
```

А если понадобится вывести список всех топпингов и в каких пиццах каждый используется?

Comment: `Toping.objects.filter(pizza__isnull=False)` - получить список топпингов используемых в пиццах. `topping.pizza_set.all()` - список пицц для топпинга.

Comment: Ну хорошо, а как в шаблоне вывести их в формате например таком: 1.Топпинг1: - пицца1, - пицца2, пицца3; 2.1.Топпинг2: - пицца1, - пицца2, пицца5?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for topping in toppings %}
Топпинг: {{ topping.name }}
{% for pizza in topping.pizza_set.all %}
    Пицца: {{ pizza.name }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Подробности тут: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_manyф](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many%D1%84)